# What is the gsettings schema for Settings > Universal Access > Sounds Keys

Tags: gnome, dconf, gsettings

look I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and currently trying to enable the sound keys from a command line but not sure where to look for the schema. At first, I thought it was `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds "true"` but I don't think that was it. I've tried to browse for it throughout `dconf-editor` but still has no idea where it's at; not to mention googled for the information many times. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the a11y settings.
Specifically it's org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard togglekeys-enable.

Reference to this answer:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424873